# Write variable to a file in Ansible

Tags: file, ansible

I am pulling JSON via the URI module and want to write the received content out to a file.  I am able to get the content and output it to the debugger so I know the content has been received, but I do not know the best practice for writing files.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

An important comment from [tmoschou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547569/tmoschou):

```
As of Ansible 2.10, The documentation for ansible.builtin.copy says:
If you need variable interpolation in copied files, use the
ansible.builtin.template module. Using a variable in the content
field will result in unpredictable output.
```

For more details see [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50580) and an [explanation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34595#issuecomment-356091161)

---

Original answer:

You could use the `copy` module, with the `content` parameter:

```
- copy: content="{{ your_json_feed }}" dest=/path/to/destination/file
```

The docs here: [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html)

Comment: content="{{ your_json_feed }}" deals with whitespace and newlines. The quotes are important.

Comment: @RamondelaFuente If I would like to add multiple vars content to the file, I need to use "copy" module multiple times or is there any other way?

Comment: @KishoreReddy I imagine you can use the jinja2 syntax to append variables. Something like "{{ variable ~ another_variable }}". Not pretty, but if things get any more complicated you could use the `template:` module and fill it with the variables registered at runtime.

Comment: This works better when you want to generate a sha256 sum file in the form `shahash  /path/to/file` (note 2 spaces between) and then validate from the command line (via `sha256sum -c shafile` ) what you generated via Ansible.

Comment: As of Ansible 2.10, The documentation for `ansible.builtin.copy` says: 

_If you need variable interpolation in copied files, use the `ansible.builtin.template` module. Using a variable in the `content` field will result in unpredictable output._

For more details see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50580 and an explanation at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34595#issuecomment-356091161

Comment: I found this answer because I was looking for a way to upload a file from an encrypted vault. Turns out, `ansible.builtin.copy` can [directly decrypt and upload](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#when-are-encrypted-files-made-visible) a file!

Comment: For human-readable output, I recommend also using  `to_nice_json` filter, for example, ```content="{{ your_json_feed | to_nice_json }}"```

Comment: Ain't *no way* I am making a `template` file that only contains the variable name instead of using `copy`. What a joke of a design choice by Ansible! They should add a new directive like `env_to_file`...

Answer (score 24):

Based on Ramon's answer I run into an error. The problem where spaces in the JSON I tried to write I got it fixed by changing the task in the playbook to look like:

```
- copy:
    content: "{{ your_json_feed }}"
    dest: "/path/to/destination/file"
```

As of now I am not sure why this was needed. My best guess is that it had something to do with how variables are replaced in Ansible and the resulting file is parsed.

Comment: Honestly, I found this to be the most helpful correct answer as it's good syntax for playbooks; although I generally add "- name: ..." to my playbook tasks.

Answer (score 23):

Unless you are writing very small files, you should probably use [templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-template-module).

Example:

```
- name: copy upstart script
  template: 
    src: myCompany-service.conf.j2 
    dest: "/etc/init/myCompany-service.conf"
```

Comment: While Ramon's answer addresses exactly what was asked, this answer is the best approach in general. For example, if you have a playbook that creates VMs in the cloud and you would like to generate an inventory of hosts for another playbook, a template is the way to go.

Comment: Can you explain why this is better?

Comment: @Vorticity better than what?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Sorry, can you explain why this is better than the accepted answer when writing large files?

Comment: @Vorticity because it becomes unwieldy when you have a file embedded in another file. you need escaping and syntax highlighting won't work. the templating mechanism enables inserting things in the middle if you need that.

Comment: This does not really answers how to write a _variable_ to a file. Templates do not cut it because for each variable you will need a different template (with that exact variable), which, if all you need is to write a variable to a file feels ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

We can directly specify the destination file with the `dest` option now. In the below example, the output json is stored into the `/tmp/repo_version_file`

```yaml
- name: Get repository file repo_version model to set ambari_managed_repositories=false
  uri:
    url: 'http://<server IP>:8080/api/v1/stacks/HDP/versions/3.1/repository_versions/1?fields=operating_systems/*'
    method: GET
    force_basic_auth: yes
    user: xxxxx
    password: xxxxx
    headers:
      "X-Requested-By": "ambari"
      "Content-type": "Application/json"
    status_code: 200
    dest: /tmp/repo_version_file
```