# Ansible - Save registered variable to file

Tags: ansible

How would I save a registered Variable to a file? I took this from the [tutorial](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables):

```
- hosts: web_servers

  tasks:

     - shell: /usr/bin/foo
       register: foo_result
       ignore_errors: True

     - shell: /usr/bin/bar
       when: foo_result.rc == 5
```

How would I save `foo_result` variable to a file e.g. `foo_result.log` using ansible?

Comment: I am wondering if you managed to find a better solution because I do not see any solution that also take care of generating a temporary file. Having to hardcode the filename would be a problem.

Comment: You  can use Variables in your dest path, too eg.: `-local_action: copy content={{var}} dest=/path/to/{{var}}.log`, but I dind't found a better solution yet / or I didn't need an other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write variable to a file in Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638180/write-variable-to-a-file-in-ansible)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Thanks to [tmoschou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547569/tmoschou) for adding this comment to an outdated accepted answer:

```
As of Ansible 2.10, The documentation for ansible.builtin.copy says: 

If you need variable interpolation in copied files, use the
ansible.builtin.template module. Using a variable in the content field will
result in unpredictable output.
```

For more details see [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50580) and an [explanation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34595#issuecomment-356091161)

---

Original answer:

You can use the `copy` module, with the parameter `content=`.

I gave the exact same answer here: [Write variable to a file in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638180/write-variable-to-a-file-in-ansible/26640778#26640778)

In your case, it looks like you want this variable written to a local logfile, so you could combine it with the `local_action` notation:

```
- local_action: copy content={{ foo_result }} dest=/path/to/destination/file
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I didn't stumbled across the previouse question. Thanx for answering again

Comment: N.P. I was actually pretty happy to find the copy module supporting this, so "how do I save to file" questions tend to catch my eye :-)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me.  I get: `FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (./the-path-to-a-local-file): sudo: a password is required\n"}`.  Why does ansible think I'm referring to a remote file?

Comment: As of Ansible 2.10, The documentation for `ansible.builtin.copy` says: 

_If you need variable interpolation in copied files, use the `ansible.builtin.template` module. Using a variable in the `content` field will result in unpredictable output._

For more details see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50580 and an explanation at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34595#issuecomment-356091161

Comment: The edit on this answer to suggest using templates is poor as it does not provide an example of how to use templates to fix the original problem

Answer (score 21):

More readable way of achieving this (not a fan of single line ansible tasks)

```
- local_action: 
    module: copy 
    content: "{{ foo_result }}"
    dest: /path/to/destination/file
```

Answer (score 16):

I am using Ansible 1.9.4 and this is what worked for me -

```
- local_action: copy content="{{ foo_result.stdout }}" dest="/path/to/destination/file"
```

Answer (score 9):

A local action will run once for each remote host (in parallel). If you want a unique file per host, make sure to put the inventory_hostname as part of the file name.

```
- local_action: copy content={{ foo_result }} dest=/path/to/destination/{{ inventory_hostname }}file
```

If you instead want a single file with all host's information, one way is to have a serial task (don't want to append in parallel) and then append to the file with a module (lineinfile is capable, or could pipe with a shell command)

```
- hosts: web_servers
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  - local_action: lineinfile line={{ foo_result }} path=/path/to/destination/file
```

Alternatively, you can  add a second play/role/task to the playbook which runs against only local host. Then access the variable from each of the hosts where the registration command ran inside a template [Access Other Hosts Variables Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)  [Template Module Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/template_module.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Gather Version
    debug:
     msg: "The server Operating system is {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
  - name: Write  Version
    local_action: shell echo "This is  {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}" >> /tmp/output
```