# Log variables to a logfile on ansible host

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that registers three variables. I want to produce a CSV report of those three variables on all hosts in my inventory.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735551/1183499) SO answer suggests to use:

`- local_action: copy content={{ foo_result }} dest=/path/to/destination/file`

But that does not append to the csv file. 
Also, I have to manually compose by comma separators in this case.

Any ideas on how to log (append) variables to a local file?

Comment: It sounds like a use case for the [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) . I am not sure if it works with csv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are wanting to append a line to a file rather than replace it's contents then this is probably best suited to the [`lineinfile`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module and utilising the module's ability to insert a line at the end of the file.

The equivalent task to the copy one that you used would be something like:

```
- name: log foo_result to file
  lineinfile:
     line: "{{ foo_result }}"
     insertafter: EOF
     dest: /path/to/destination/file
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Note that I've used the long hand for [delegating tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) locally rather than `local_action`. I personally feel that the syntax reads a lot clearer but you could easily use the following instead if you prefer the more compact syntax of `local_action`:

```
- local_action: lineinfile line={{ foo_result }} insertafter=EOF dest=/path/to/destination/file
```

Comment: Nice, this works well, thank you. I'm generally surprised there is not a more general way to write these types of reports in csv, json, etc, etc.