# How to write a dictionary variable to the file in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to save a set of the registered variables as a dictionary to a file.
I can find the solution to save multiple variables to a file here
[Ansible: Save registered variables to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942408/ansible-save-registered-variables-to-file?rq=1)
But I want to be able to save the variables as a dictionary

```
---
- name: Get variable1
  shell: "some java command"
  register: variable1

- name: Get variable2
  shell: "some java command"
  register: variable2
```

Now, I want to save them to a file in the form of dictionary like

```
dictionary_variable:
   var1: "{{ variable1 }}"
   var2: "{{ variable2 }}"
```

I should be able to access the dictionary like

```
{{ dictionary_variable.var1 }} or {{ dictionary_variable.var2 }}
```

Comment: You can try one of the filters [in here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data). I recommend using `{{ var | to_nice_json }}` in your `local_action` task. I say this, because a _json_ file is practically a file with a dictionary inside.