# Get exactly data from "stdout" or "stdout_lines" with exact words of output

Tags: ansible, zimbra

I have a task

```yaml
- name: DELEGATED ADMIN ACCOUNTS - check, get and send to the file domain.list
  shell: /opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov -l gaaa -v zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount
```

and after this task I got output

```json
changed: [Shrrah] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "sh",
        "/home/information_domain.sh"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:02.495922",
    "end": "2022-03-29 10:25:16.936051",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "sh /home/information_domain.sh",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2022-03-29 10:25:14.440129",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "# name admin@shrrah.esquimail.com\nzimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: FALSE\n\n# name prueba5@prueba5.com\n\n# name prueba7@prueba7.com\nzimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE\n\n# name prueba9@prueba9.com",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "# name admin@shrrah.esquimail.com",
        "zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: FALSE",
        "",
        "# name prueba5@prueba5.com",
        "",
        "# name prueba7@prueba7.com",
        "zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE",
        "",
        "# name prueba9@prueba9.com"
    ]
}
```

I need to get data with `n# name prueba7@prueba7.com\nzimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE` from `"stdout"` or from `"stdout_lines"` in format:

```
prueba7@prueba7.com zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE
```

or

```
prueba7@prueba7.com
zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE
```

and send it to the `file.txt`. Number of lines can be different (one o more users with domain).

I have no idea how I can do this, is this possible? If you know could you please help with advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a look into [`debug` – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html), [Using Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) and [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    RESULT:
      STDOUT_LINES:
        - "# name admin@shrrah.esquimail.com"
        - "zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: FALSE"
        - ""
        - "# name prueba5@prueba5.com"
        - ""
        - "# name prueba7@prueba7.com"
        - "zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE"
        - ""
        - "# name prueba9@prueba9.com"

  tasks:

  - name: Show STDOUT_LINES
    debug:
      msg: "{{ RESULT.STDOUT_LINES }}"
```

resulting into an output only of

```yaml
TASK [Show STDOUT_LINES] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - '# name admin@shrrah.esquimail.com'
  - 'zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: FALSE'
  - ''
  - '# name prueba5@prueba5.com'
  - ''
  - '# name prueba7@prueba7.com'
  - 'zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE'
  - ''
  - '# name prueba9@prueba9.com'
```

and if Ansible [Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) is configured to YAML instead of JSON.

To get lines containing certain strings only you may [Loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) over the [list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) based on a [Condition](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

```yaml
  - name: Show lines with TRUE only
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: "'TRUE' in item"
    loop: "{{ RESULT.STDOUT_LINES }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show lines with TRUE only] *******************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE) =>
  msg: 'zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE'
```

**Further Documenation**

- [Index of all Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)

---

If you like to have the line before included, you could use an approach like

```yaml
  - name: Show lines with TRUE and line before
    debug:
      msg: "{{ RESULT.STDOUT_LINES[ansible_loop.index0 - 1] }}\n{{ item }}"
    when: "'TRUE' in item"
    loop: "{{ RESULT.STDOUT_LINES }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show lines with TRUE and line before] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=6) =>
  msg: |-
    # name prueba7@prueba7.com
    zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)

---

Since you are using the `shell` module, you could use also an approach like

```yaml
- name: DELEGATED ADMIN ACCOUNTS - check, get and send to the file domain.list
  shell: 
    cmd: /opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov -l gaaa -v zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount | grep -B 1 TRUE
```

and gather only result lines which are `true` an the line before.

**Further Q&A**

- [`grep` a file, but show several surrounding lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083/6771046)

---

Regarding

> ... send it to the `file.txt`

you may have a look into

- [Ansible - Save registered variable to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732241/)
- [Ansible: Save registered variables to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942408/)
- ...

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Very Very clear answer!!

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        info: "{{ info|d({})|combine({_key: _val}) }}"
      loop: "{{ stdout.split('#')[1:] }}"
      vars:
        _list: "{{ item.split('\n')|map('trim') }}"
        _key: "{{ _list.0.split(' ')|last }}"
        _val: "{{ _list[1:]|select()|map('from_yaml')|combine }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  info:
    admin@shrrah.esquimail.com:
      zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: false
    prueba5@prueba5.com: {}
    prueba7@prueba7.com:
      zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: true
    prueba9@prueba9.com: {}
```

Then, the template is trivial. Either print all items

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: |-
          {% for k,v in info.items() %}
          {{ k }}
          {{ v|to_nice_yaml }}
          {% endfor %}
        dest: file.txt
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat file.txt 
admin@shrrah.esquimail.com
zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: false

prueba5@prueba5.com
{}

prueba7@prueba7.com
zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: true

prueba9@prueba9.com
{}
```

, or explicitly select item(s)

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: |-
          prueba7@prueba7.com
          {{ info['prueba7@prueba7.com']|to_nice_yaml }}
        dest: file.txt
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat file.txt 
prueba7@prueba7.com
zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: true
```

---

**Note**

Additional attributes will be parsed too, e.g.

```yaml
    stdout_lines: [
      "# name admin@shrrah.esquimail.com",
      "zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: FALSE",
      "",
      "# name prueba5@prueba5.com",
      "",
      "# name prueba7@prueba7.com",
      "zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: TRUE",
      "zimbraIsDelegatedRootAccount: TRUE",
      "",
      "# name prueba9@prueba9.com"
    ]
```

will give

```yaml
  info:
    admin@shrrah.esquimail.com:
      zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: false
    prueba5@prueba5.com: {}
    prueba7@prueba7.com:
      zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: true
      zimbraIsDelegatedRootAccount: true
    prueba9@prueba9.com: {}
```

and consequently

```yaml
shell> cat file.txt 
prueba7@prueba7.com
zimbraIsDelegatedAdminAccount: true
zimbraIsDelegatedRootAccount: true
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, I am very appreciate for this answer!!!