# Ansible un-vault and template a file

Tags: templates, jinja2, ansible, ansible-vault

I have a file on my local machine that I want to upload to a remote server, it contains confidential information that I don't want exposed in my VCS. It also has some text I need to replace dynamically in it (at the moment as Jinja2 placeholders "{{}}").

If I use the copy module, then the file is un-vaulted when I upload it, but obviously the placeholders are note replaced.

If i use the template module, then it doesn't un-vault the file and hence it is uploaded in its encrypted format (and also doesn't replace placeholders because they are obfuscated by the encryption).

How can I both template and un-vault a file (using ansible) to the remote server?

Comment: Why not create variables for that parts that you want to keep secret and then just use the template module after vaulting the secret vars?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I think that in some edge cases you might not want to reveal your configuration files - and putting the whole config template into a secret var string is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you could set your secrets in variables and render them into the templates during provision, but if for some reason you want to keep your whole template a secret, there are some workarounds to also do that.

### Handling encrypted templates

As a workaround you could temporarily decrypt the template locally and after the rollout delete the decrypted file with the `local_action` module. 
Lets assume your encrypted template resides as `template.enc` in your roles `templates` directory.

```
---

- name: Decrypt template
  local_action: "shell {{ view_encrypted_file_cmd }} {{ role_path }}/templates/template.enc > {{ role_path }}/templates/template"
  changed_when: False

- name: Deploy template
  template:
    src=templates/template
    dest=/home/user/file

- name: Remove decrypted template
  local_action: "file path={{ role_path }}/templates/template state=absent"
  changed_when: False
```

Please note the `changed_when: False`. This is important in order to run idempotence tests with your ansible roles - otherwise each time you run the playbook a change is signaled.
In `group_vars/all.yml` you could set a global decrypt command for reuse, e.g., as `view_encrypted_file_cmd`.

*group_vars/all.yml*

```
---

view_encrypted_file_cmd: "ansible-vault --vault-password-file {{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE') }} view"
```

### Handling encrypted static files

**One way: as template**

You could set the content of your secret static file (e.g., a private key) as a variable in ansible and provision it as a template.

*var.yml*

```
---

my_private_key: |
  YOUR KEY
  asfdlsafkj
  asdlkfjasf
```

*templates/private_key.j2*

```
{{ private_key }}
```

*tasks/main.yml*

```
---

template: 
  src=templates/private_key.j2
  dest=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
  vars:
    private_key: "{{ my_private_key }}"
```

**Another way: via lookup pipe**

Another way would be to use the `lookup` module with `pipe` to set the `content` property within the `copy` module - that way you do not need an extra variable.

```
---

- copy:
    dest=/your/dest
    content=lookup('pipe', 'VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=path/to/pass_file ansible-vault view path/to/file.enc')
```

Answer (score 6):

Now Ansible 2.4 supports decrypt option on copy module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html#options

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be used any more, see [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682928/ansible-un-vault-and-template-a-file/44154978?noredirect=1#comment124384854_44154978) below...

---

There is another possibility similar to the [solution by fishi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685203/1165155) in case of a static file. By using `copy` instead of `template` there is no need for an additional file.

## Using `vars.yml`:

Store in a vault-encrypted *vars.yml*:

```
encrypted_content: |
  foo = {{ bar }}
  password = abcabc
  ...
```

Code for the task:

```
- name: Save encrypted template
  copy: 
    content: "{{ encrypted_content }}"
    dest: /path/to/destination
```

## Using a separate YAML file

You can also store the encrypted template code in another YAML file. This is useful, wenn `vars.yml` shall not be encrypted. For example `vars/encrypted.yml` might be:

```
encrypted_content: |
  foo = {{ bar }}
  password = abcabc
  ...
```

Code for the task:

```
- name: Read encrypted variable file
  include_vars: encrypted.yml
  no_log: true

- name: Save encrypted template
  copy: 
    content: "{{ encrypted_content }}"
    dest: /path/to/destination
```

Comment: [According to Ansible’s documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640778/735926) "`Using a variable in the content field will result in unpredictable output.`" so this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In short, use `copy` module and `ansible-vault`.

Here is the complete example for copying a local encrypted file named `hello.vault` to `hello.txt` on remote server. Its clear content is `WORLD` and the encryption key is `1234`.

1. Create your vault file `hello.vault`:

```sh
$ ansible-vault create hello.vault
New Vault password: 1234
Confirm New Vault password: 1234
## Then input your secret and exit the editor ##
WORLD

$ cat hello.vault
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
39653932393834613339393036613931393636663638636331323034653036326237373061666139
6434373635373065613135633866333733356532616635640a663739306639326535336637616138
39666462343737653030346463326464333937333161306561333062663164313162376564663262
3533393839633466300a666661303363383265613736376564623465613165656531366331366664
6436
```

2. Create your password file, e.g. `vault.key` as follow

```
1234
```

3. Use `copy` module to transfer the vault file to clear text on `webserver`(defined in inventory).

```
ansible webserver -i inventory --vault-password-file=vault.key \
        -m copy -a "src=hello.vault dest=hello.txt"

ansible webserver -i inventory -m command -a "cat hello.txt"
WORLD
```