# Ansible - Log stdout lines from each remote host to a single file on the local server

Tags: ansible

Is there an easy way to log output from multiple remote hosts to a single file on the server running `ansible-playbook`?

I have a variable called `validate` which stores the output of a command executed on each server. I want to take `validate.stdout_lines` and drop the lines from each host into one file locally.

Here is one of the snippets I wrote but did not work:

```
- name: Write results to logfile
  blockinfile:
    create: yes
    path: "/var/log/ansible/log"
    insertafter: BOF
    block: "{{ validate.stdout }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

When I executed my playbook w/ the above, it was only able to capture the output from one of the remote hosts. I want to capture the lines from *all* hosts in that single /var/log/ansible/log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should do is to add a `marker` to the `blockinfile` to wrap the result from each single host in a unique block.

The second problem is that the tasks would run in parallel (even with `delegate_to: localhost`, because the loop here is realised by the Ansible engine) with effectively one task overwriting the other's `/var/log/ansible/log` file.

As a quick workaround you can serialise the whole play:

```
- hosts: ...
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Write results to logfile
      blockinfile:
        create: yes
        path: "/var/log/ansible/log"
        insertafter: BOF
        block: "{{ validate.stdout }}"
        marker: "# {{ inventory_hostname }} {mark}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

The above produces the intended result, but if serial execution is a problem, you might consider writing your own loop for this single task (for ideas refer to [support for "serial" on an individual task #12170](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12170)).

---

Speaking of other methods, in two tasks: you can concatenate the results into a single list (no issue with parallel execution then, but pay attention to [delegated facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts)) and then write to a file using `copy` module (see [Write variable to a file in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638180/write-variable-to-a-file-in-ansible)).

Comment: Thanks techraf! Using your references I was able to devise a solution, which I appended to your response.