# Create file from variable in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I want to create a file (namely an `id_rsa` key) using `ansible`.

It seems that using the `copy` builtin module is no longer [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640778/2409793) and users are advised to use `template`.

If I understand correcly, I will have to put the contents of the `id_rsa` to an `id_rsa.j2` and then render it on the target host.

This of course will then have to be encrypted with `ansible-vault`.

My question is whether there is a workaround (since I already have a `vars` file with secrets) so that I add the contents of the private key to this (already encrypted) file to avoid adding yet another encrypted file just for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't put any sensitive information in your template, just the variable name, the same way you would have with `copy` + `content`.

```
{{ my_private_key_var }}
```