# How to use variable value for a spesific variable file content in Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

For example i have variable A and I want to write a file B with these value from variable A. The value from var A will be vary from the survey input.

```
- hosts: myhost
      vars:
        A: "{{ input }}"
```

The content of the file B that I needed:
A="{{ input }}"

I need to replace the input for the file from the input value in the variable. The input can be anything inserted in the ansible survey.

Is there a way to write the input values from var A to the file B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question and description are very vague

> Is there a way to write the input values from var A to the file B?

the answer might not fit fully to your use case.

You may use the [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#examples)_module.

First create a file

**variable.file.j2**

```
A={{ A }}
```

and than write it to the destination.

```
- name: Template a file to /tmp/B
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: variable.file.j2
    dest: /tmp/B
```

Thanks to

- [Write variable to a file in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638180/)
- [Ansible - Save registered variable to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732241/)

Comment: actually, the input will be vary to the input in the survey, so input may be different each time.. i tried using the solution but it only echo the exact A="{{ input }}" and not the input A,B,C that i need

Comment: Regarding your objection "_...the input will be vary to the input in the survey, so input may be different each time..._", yes, a template will handle that too. Regarding "_...I tried using..._", can you show by editing in your initial question what you have tried and what was the result?

Comment: i used it wrong thats why it didnt work, i tried this again and it works fine thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Templating would indeed be better. The quick 'n dirty method would be:

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_hosts
  vars:
    A: my_value
  tasks:
    - shell: "echo {{ A }} > /tmp/B"
      register: the_echo
```

This way you'll see what's happening