# Add a file on my control node with ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I launch a script which give me some informations on my devices but I have the result only in my Ansible Console.
I would like to have this informations on a file on my control manager.
In the script they are store in the variable $Ansible.Result.

How can I put it in a file ?

Code of my playbook.yaml

```
- name: firsttest
  hosts: win
  tasks:
   - name: Ping my Windows vm
     win_ping:

   - name: Run basic PowerShell script
     ansible.windows.win_powershell:
       script: |
         $hostname = hostname
         $domain = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Domain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $private = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Private | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $public = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Public | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $ipaddress = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress | Out-String

         $myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
          "Hostname" = $hostname
          "IPAdress" = $ipaddress
          "Domain" = $domain
          "Private" = $private
          "Public" = $public
         }
         $Ansible.Result = $myObject
     register: result

   - name: Show PS_output
     debug:
       var: result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to use delegate_to on my loopback address (127.0.0.1) like that this task can be execute on my control node (This task is execute for each asset present in my inventory).

```
   - name: Stock the result in a file on my control node
     lineinfile: 
       dest: "/home/user/mydata.txt"
       line: "{{ result }}"
       create: yes
     delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

The task above create a file txt on my control manager which contains my variable result.

Answer (score 0):

The question pretty much duplicates [Write variable to a file in Ansible, answer with using template module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37377161/17052885)

So assuming that you don't follow not recommended use of variable in `content` parameter of `copy` module, then you should create result.j2 in `templates/` with just one line {{ result }} inside this file and then use `template` module as given in answer above.

Comment: Yeah but I want my result in a file on my control node, not on the remote host.