# How yo print API request and response with Ansible uri module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I tried to find a way to print both an API request and response to a log file. But Ansible URI module does not provide the request data.

Does anyone know any mechanism to print the request and response to file in Ansible?

example:

```
 name: update cms
  uri:
    url:  '{{ cms_api.msg }}'
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body:
      api_password: "{{ api_password  }}"
      name: "{{ item.Name }}"
      ip_address: "{{ item.IPAddress }}"
      subnet_mask: "{{ item.SubnetMask }}"
      router: "{{ item.Router }}"
      ip_range: "{{ item.IPAddresses }}"
      options: "{{ item.Options }}"
      pool_name: "{{ item.PoolName}}" 
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
  register: dhcp_subnet_response
  loop: "{{ ip_addrs_1.list }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I need to print above request and response both to a file. Since this api calling as a loop, I need to print request|response both for each request.

Comment: `I tried to find a way to print api request and response...`. please [edit] your question and add your code. Describe the exact problem you're having. Before you proceed, you'll want to read [ask] paying a particular attention to the [mre] section.

Comment: Even after an update it is still a requirement, but no description or question about what or where is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your post contains several different questions you may have a look into the general documentation first

- [Registering Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)
- [Return Values - Common](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common)
- [`uri` module – Interacts with webservices - Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#return-values) and their [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#examples)

After reading and regarding

> *But Ansible URI module not providing request data.*

you may then have a look into the following example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get response with 'uri' module
    uri:
      url: "https://example.com"
      method: GET
      body_format: raw     # default
      return_content: true # default 'false'
      status_code: 200
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

resulting into the content of https://example.com, an [IANA-managed Reserved Domain](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved).

> *Does anyone know any mechanism to print ...*

The page content itself is accessible via

```yaml
  - name: Show content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.content }}"
```

> *print ... to file in Ansible?*

and you can [Write variable to a file in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638180/) or [Ansible - Save registered variable to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732241/).

Comment: Yes. I know and with this example, you may able to get only the response data. My requirement is to print request and response both in to file.

Comment: That might be your requirement, but what is your question? With the information provided all necessary parts are available to achieve that.

Comment: I updated my question with code. I just need to print request data first and response data for perticular request.